# Метки "security" и "безопасность"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На ru.SO есть 2, как мне кажется, одинаковые по смыслу метки: [security](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) - 69 вопросов и [безопасность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) - 198 вопросов. Возможно, их стоит объединить?